# Cannot Render Images onto Canvas for Game Using getContext

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, call

I have the following code.  I am trying to get my HTML site to render the background image (bg) and the pipe images (pipeNorth and pipeSouth) on my canvas.

I am using chrome.

**1st CODE ATTEMPT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flappy Bird using JS | by Pinzhi</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h3>flappyBird by pineNuts</h3>

   <canvas id="canvas" width="288" height="512"></canvas>


   <script>

   var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas")
   var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d"); 

    // create variables

    var gap = 75; 
    var constant = pipeNorth.height + gap; 

    // load images

    var bird = new Image(); 
    var bg = new Image(); 
    var fg = new Image();  
    var pipeNorth = new Image(); 
    var pipeSouth = new Image();  

    bird.src = "/home/pinzhi/Desktop/js_games/flappy_bird/templates/images/bird.png"; 
    bg.src = "/home/pinzhi/Desktop/js_games/flappy_bird/templates/images/bg.png";

    //fg.src = "images/fg.png";
    pipeNorth.src = "images/pipeNorth.png";
    pipeSouth.src = "images/pipeSouth.png";


    // draw images 

    function draw(){

        ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0); 
        ctx.drawImage(pipeNorth, 100, 0); 
        ctx.drawImage(pipeSouth, 100, 0 + constant)
    }

    draw(); 



   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**2nd CODE ATTEMPT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flappy Bird using JS | by Pinzhi</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h3>flappyBird by pineNuts</h3>

   <canvas id="canvas" width="288" height="512"></canvas>


   <script>

   var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas")
   var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d"); 

    // create variables

    var gap = 75; 
    var constant = pipeNorth.height + gap; 

    // load images

    var bird = new Image(); 
    var bg = new Image(); 
    var fg = new Image();  
    var pipeNorth = new Image(); 
    var pipeSouth = new Image();  


    bg.onload = function(e) {
     ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0);
    }

     pipeNorth.onload = function(e) {
     ctx.drawImage(e.target, 100, 0);
    }

    pipeSouth.onload = function(e) {
     ctx.drawImage(e.target, 100, 0 + constant);
   }



   bg.src = "/home/pinzhi/Desktop/js_games/flappy_bird/templates/images/bg.png";
   pipeNorth.src = "images/pipeNorth.png";
   pipeSouth.src = "images/pipeSouth.png";



    // // draw images 

    // function draw(){

    //     ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0); 
    //     ctx.drawImage(pipeNorth, 100, 0); 
    //     ctx.drawImage(pipeSouth, 100, 0 + constant)
    // }

    // draw(); 



   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But no matter what I try, I can't get the images to show up.  My code is in the template folder.  The template folder contains a sub-folder called "images" that contains my pictures.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're drawing the images only once, immediately after setting their src. Are you sure the images have even loaded by the time you draw them? You might want to wait until the image `load` event fires before drawing.

Comment: Try using `bird.onload` to ensure the image has loaded before attempting to render it.

Comment: you are calling `bg.onload` twice, and 3rd onload `pipeSouth.drawImage(e.target, 100, 0 + constant);` needs to change to `ctx.drawImage(e.target, 100, 0 + constant);`

Comment: @ Daz Chest: I made the edits you suggested (see my updated original post) but still cannot render any images on my html ... thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you need to check the console for errors. You are trying to get the height before the image is loaded - `var constant = pipeNorth.height + gap;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you're trying to draw them right after setting the Image's **.src** property. At this time it might not be loaded yet so you need to wait for the **onload** event before calling drawImage().

```
   bg.onload = function(e) {
     ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0);
   }
   pipeNorth.onload = function(e) {
     ctx.drawImage(e.target, 100, 0);
   }
   pipeSouth.onload = function(e) {
     ctx.drawImage(e.target, 100, 0 + constant);
   }

   bg.src = "/home/pinzhi/Desktop/js_games/flappy_bird/templates/images/bg.png";
   pipeNorth.src = "images/pipeNorth.png";
   pipeSouth.src = "images/pipeSouth.png";
```

Here's an example using your code:

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var constant;
// create variables

var gap = 75;

// load images

var bird = new Image();
var bg = new Image();
var fg = new Image();
var pipeNorth = new Image();
var pipeSouth = new Image();

var imagesLoaded = 0;
bg.onload = function(e) {
  imagesLoaded++;
  draw();
}
pipeNorth.onload = function(e) {
  imagesLoaded++;
  constant = pipeNorth.height + gap;
  draw();
}
pipeSouth.onload = function(e) {
  imagesLoaded++;
  draw();
}

function draw() {
  if (imagesLoaded == 3) {
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(pipeNorth, 100, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(pipeSouth, 100, 0 + constant);
  }
}

bg.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/719/288/512";
pipeNorth.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/71/64/64";
pipeSouth.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/76/64/64";
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="288" height="512"></canvas>
```

Comment: I tried your code above, but my html site is still not rendering any of those images

Comment: I slightly changed my code above - for other reasons though. The order in which the images finish loading might be different so you're background would eventually get drawn on top of the other images. Anyhow, the code is working. Check the example. Maybe simply the url to your images is wrong?

Comment: thank you so much; I think I'm unable to pick up those images from the folder

Comment: No problem @PineNuts0 - glad I could help!